# Make multiple rows of a row in another sheet with something appended

Tags: excel

I have 2 sheets, one called prices and one called list. In the prices sheet, I have a list of items with it's price. Like this:

```
+-----------+--------+
| Item name | Price  |
+-----------+--------+
| potato    | $1.30  |
| onion     |  $1.50 |
+-----------+--------+
```

Now for each item in my prices table, I want to have 5 rows in my list table. Like this:

```
+-------------+---------------------------+
|  Item name  | some other stuff here.... |
+-------------+---------------------------+
| potato 1kg  |                           |
| potato 500g |                           |
| potato 250g |                           |
| potato 100g |                           |
| potato 50g  |                           |
| onion 1kg   |                           |
| onion 500g  |                           |
| onion 250g  |                           |
| onion 100g  |                           |
| onion 50g   |                           |
+-------------+---------------------------+
```

I want to have this with no VBA because I would later convert this to google sheets for sharing purposes...

I've tried to use INDEX with this formula....

`=INDEX(prices!4:1002,CEILING(ROWS($1:3)/5,1),1)`

But I only get the items one time... I know i have to use index in some way but not sure how exactly

Comment: Which version of Excel do you have?

Comment: i use excel 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your `some other stuff here....`, but this will get the permutations:

```
=arrayformula({"Item Name";flatten(if(Sheet1!A2:A<>"",Sheet1!A2:A&" "&{"1Kg","500g","250g","100g","50g"},))})
```

Instead of the fixed array `{"1Kg","500g","250g","100g","50g"}`, you could use a table.

I've shown the formula on the same sheet, but you could move it to your second sheet, and update `Sheet1!` accordingly.

[image]